# MS CRM: SetStateRequest and business rules conflict

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

I have a problem.

I use `SetStateRequest()` to change status of incident. Both statuses have `StateCode = 0`, but when I send request it activates business rule, which is triggered by changing Incident StateCode to `0`, but I don't need that, how can I bypass activating that trigger?

Also tried to get entity using Context, then changing `Incident.StatusCode`, updating it and then using `context.SaveChanges();`

Both of this triggers this business rule

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It’s unclear what you’re asking. Do you have entity level business rules? If you want that to trigger only on forms - change the scope of Business rule from Entity to All forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the status of the record, and both the initial status and target status are Active statuses, then you can do this in an Update request instead of a SetStateRequest. This will result in an update to the statuscode field, but not the statecode field.

```
//Swap in whatever status you want    
updateIncident.statuscode = new OptionSetValue(incident_statuscode.InProgress.ToInt());
service.Update(updateIncident);
```